# Potential across the plate of a capacitor

Tags: potential, capacitance

So I came across this question:

> Two capacitors are connected in series of given capacitance $5\ \mu\mathrm F$ and $10\ \mu\mathrm F$. The first plate of the $5\ \mu\mathrm F$ capacitor is given a potential of $100\ \mathrm V$ and the second plate of the $10\ \mu\mathrm F$ capacitor is earthed. Find the potential of the other two plates.

So when they say that the 2nd plate is earthed, does it imply that the circuit is completed and also is the potential of each plate nothing but the potential of the capacitor?

Comment: Definitely a poorly worded problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the circuit is not complete. 
If it were complete Capacitors would discharge and 1st plate would have 0 potential.
Next, potential of capacitor and plate are different.
Capacitor has potential difference b/w two plates.

Since both are connected in series net Capacitance = 10/3 uF .
$$Q = CV = 10/3 *100 = 1000/3 uC$$

which is charge on both capacitors.
$$Q = CV$$
$$1000/3 = 5 * V_{1}$$

$$V_{1} = 200/3$$

Comment: Then what would be the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the arrangement looks something like this?

[image]

Comment: There is no image with the question but that is probably right